# Lock on IBM DB2 database on Linux server

Tags: linux, database

My db2 database is running on Linux server,

Some time database table got lock by some of db user due to uncommiting the session.

My question is that how we can find out through which machine/dbuser/ip database table got lock. if anyone have any idea abt same please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can use db2top and check the current sessions. Once you see a lock wait, you analyze the corresponding agent.

You can also get a snapshot on lock, and this will returns the whole information about locking.

You can use the db2 list applications show detail to see the current status of the applications.

Or you can even use the db2pd in order to get information about the transaction.

Finally, there are several table functions and administrative views to see what is happening in the database.